# Storing times - use Time or Int field? (PHP & mySQL Database)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Consider the SQL query below:

```
SELECT * FROM opening_hours  
        WHERE week_day = WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 1 
              AND open_hour =< date_format(now(),'%H:%i') 
              AND close_hour >= date_format(now(),'%H:%i')
```

`open_hour` / `close_hour` fields are TIME type.

I am using MySQL.

Suppose that open_time is "18:00", close_time is "02:00", current time is "22:41". We have a separate DB record for the close_time (cause it's after midnight), but we will never get it in the result, because the close_time "02:00" is NOT greater than the current time, "22:41".

Also if current time is "01:00", we will get the NEXT day values, because the weekday doesn't match.

**Solution?**

Would you rather store these values in integer (minutes), so the php is able to process these values directly, without any conversion?

For example...

Current time:

```
$timearr = explode(':',date("w:H:i"));
$currenttime = ($timearr[0]) * 1440 + $timearr[1] * 60 + $timearr[2]
```

Minimal value of current time = 0 (Sun, 00:00), max value is 10079 (Sat, 23:59)

In the database, the stored open/close time values may be between 0 and 11519 (Sat, 47:59)

Now suppose, that the current time is "Sun, 01:00" (first day of week), executing  the above coversion this value is 60; and the open/close times for last day of week (Saturday) are set to "17:00" and "02:00" (which is actually Sunday), stored in the DB as 9660 and 10200 (Saturday, 26:00). In this case, the above query will not find the record we need (Sat, 17:00, 02:00), because we probably don't have any open_time less than "02:00" (120). To solve this, we convert "Sun, 01:00" to "Sat, 25:00", by adding 7*1440 (a whole week) to the $currenttime, which will result 10140. Then DB query like this:

```
SELECT open_time,clos_time FROM open_hours 
    WHERE (open_time <= $currenttime 
         AND close_time >= $currenttime)
         OR (open_time <= $currenttime +10080
         AND close_time >= $currenttime + 10080);
```

Or what is alternative and neater solution?

Comment: I have a question: Are you wanting to store every day's open and close times, as in 365/366 a year, or just the Monday through Sunday type?

Comment: Then use an integer representation as @AlienWebGuy suggests. Something like `71000` for `Sunday 10 am` or `42230` for `Thursday 10:30 pm`. You don't really need a date/time type field.

Comment: thx for suggestion, I wonder what the purpose of time type? What is freaking me out is that storing as INT for minutes values look really messy:)

Comment: Well, you know I was getting it and `time()` in PHP confused and was thinking it was like a timestamp, not just the formatted time only. Sorry about that. I still would say you could do the integer method just as easily, it would just depend on if you want to translate the values back to a "human-readable" format or not. It is less DB-vendor specific, as well, which may or may not be a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INT` since not all databases support `DATE` fields, or support them in the same way. `INT` is much more portable and it's just as easy to figure out your date with the integer timestamp if you choose to go that route.

Comment: I am using mySQL Server. It support Time and Date. My question was should I use INT or Time type for my solution.

Comment: I wouldn't even use a `Time` type. Integers exclusively. I've even heard from DBA's to use `INT` or `TINYINT` as 1/0 fields instead of `BOOL` for even further portability, but that's another discussion entirely :)

Comment: Any database that doesn't have temporal data types is just a toy, and should not be used.

Comment: @NullUserException: Because Michael Durant's answer "I have learned from experience to always store things for what they are and use datatypes appropriately ..." is absolutely the correct one, even though in comments on this answer he says "Yeah as a dba I would go with int."

Answer (score 7):

I have learned from experience to always store things for what they are and use datatypes appropriately so I would recommend the time or date-time option.  As you start to do anything else with it it is better to have it in the correct format and just cast it for display, sorting, etc.

All the SQL databases I know support date / date/time / time formats, certainly mysql.

If you ever need to move it i.e. export it to another db or format you'll be using a tool (even if just a sql script) that will have the ability to cast it to another format or type.

Comment: I actually like this answer too. I have at times wished I didn't use unix timestamps in a particular field and could use the native date/time comparison and other database functions. Put simply, I used timestamps because I was more comfortable with them, not because they were the right approach for that field.

Comment: @Michael If I were to use TIME type field - how to solve problem if the closing time is after midnight? read my question again, thanks

Comment: @user791022 - The MySQL [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) type allows you to go up to `838:59:59` in a value, so you could do `26:00:00` for `2 am`, you'd just have to handle it in your PHP code as such.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, I totally agree with it and I think this is the best practice. I have been developer for about 5 years and I have learned, like you, that data types exist for a reason.

Comment: @Mario you need to think outside your bubble. Often times software has proprietary data types or object properties that create portability issues. If portability is not a concern, then of course use the available features to their fullest extent.

Comment: I generally agree with this answer more, however in relation to the question, I think it depends on the specific project scope. If portability is in scope, then do it the portable way (the accepted answer). If you are building with the reasonable assumption of an expected server environment (ie: LAMP stack, IIS, etc), do it whichever way works the most optimally for that specific environment.